# How to sum a column of percentages in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a column of percentages

```
Profitpercent
25.5
65.1
61
30.8
34
```

I want the sum of that column in percentage. I can't use SUM() function on it directly as percentage can't be over 100%. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: Do you need to calculate `AVG()`?

Comment: It looks like you need to sum the sources of the percentage calculation and then recalculate the overall percentage? Do you have the source components of the percentage available? Can we see a representation of your table?

Comment: Please update the question. You both want to know how to sum the data and do NOT want to sum the column data.  Unless you can express your question better, I won't be able to help.

Comment: I need to calculate the sum or total of the percentage column in percentage.

Answer (score 3):

if there two percentage value like 25% and 43% then adding them would be

```
(25+43)/(100+100) = 68/200
```

In that way, you could do something like below (may not be accurate since your percentage values include fractions as well)

```
select sum(Profitpercent)/(count(Profitpercent)*100) as SumOfProfitpercent
from some_table
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it.

Comment: this answer is the same as above. sum()/count() = avg()

Answer (score 2):

Something like the average? Try this

```
SELECT AVG (ProfitPercent)
FROM YourProfitTable
```

Here some info about it:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp

Comment: I don't want the average of the column. I want the total of that column in percentage.

Comment: Yeah, but you said that the percentage can´t be over 100%. And if you sum all the percentages..